# Buffer bindings of transform feedback objects

Tags: opengl

using OpenGL 4.5 and an NVidia card, I have noticed that when switching transform feedback objects via `glBindTransformFeedback()`, the associated array buffer bindings established with `glBindBufferBase()`, do not get changed.

Have a look at the following snippets:

Let there be a pair of transform feedback and vertex buffer objects:

```
GLuint tfo1, vbo1;
glGenTransformFeedbacks(1, &tfo1);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 123 * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tfo1);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, vbo1);
```

Query result using `glGetIntegerv()`:

```
GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BINDING: 1
GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER_BINDING: 1
```

Let there be another pair of such objects:

```
GLuint tfo2, vbo2;
glGenTransformFeedbacks(1, &tfo2);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 123 * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tfo2);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, vbo2);
```

Query result using `glGetIntegerv()`:

```
GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BINDING: 2
GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER_BINDING: 2
```

And now comes the issue: After having created the second pair, binding the previous transform buffer object `tfo1`...

```
glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tfo1);
```

...leads to the following query result:

```
GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BINDING: 1
GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER_BINDING: 2   <--- WHY NOT 1?
```

The bound TFO is now `tfo1` but the array buffer binding has not been changed.
**It looks like as if the buffer binding is not part of the TFO state but can that be?** Isn't managing buffer bindings the main reason TFOs exist?

Comment: "*Isn't managing buffer bindings the main reason TFOs exist?*" No; the main reason feedback objects exist is to be able to pause and resume feedback operations. Granted, they do contain buffer object bindings. But you should show us the *actual code* where you query this stuff. Because I strongly suspect you're not querying the buffer correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf), both the generic `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER_BINDING` (which is to be queried with `glGetIntegerv` as well as the indexed bindings (to be queried with `glGetIntegeri_v`) are part of the transform feedback object state. Section 13.2.1 "Transform Feedback Objects" states (emphasis mine)

> A transform feedback object is created by binding a name returned by `GenTransformFeedbacks` with the command
>   `void BindTransformFeedback( enum target, uint id );`
>   **The resulting transform feedback object is a new state vector, comprising all the state and with the same initial values listed in table 23.48.**

with table 23.48 containing both:

> ```
> TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER_BINDING | Z+   | GetIntegerv   | 0 | Buffer object bound to generic bind point for transform feedback 
> TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER_BINDING |n x Z+| GetIntegeri_v | 0 | Buffer object bound to each transform feedback attribute stream
> [...]
> ```

So, in your example, switching back to `tfo1` also should restore the generic transform buffer feedback binding back to `vbo1`. I tried your example. On an AMD implementation (Windows 7, Firepro 15.201.2401 drivers), it is behaving as the spec says. However, with NVidia (Linux, 370.28), I got the same result you are describing. What is funny is that even Nvidia's own version of transfrom feedback objects from [`GL_NV_transform_feedback2`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/transform_feedback2.txt) uses similar language, and explicitely defines the generic binding as part as the transform feedback object state. So I'd say that you just hit some Nvidia bug.